# Row onClick affecting other rows

Tags: java, android, listview, view

I am creating a check list for marking "students" present or absent.
I have a listView creating successfully with their details and to the right; an ImageView "X". When you tap the row the "X" changes to a tick! And it successfully changes other things that I need for this program to work.

My problem "was", when I would scroll one of the "ticked" rows out of view it would revert back to an "X". I have solved this using a View Holder.

My current problem is that, for example, in a List of 6 students. If I "tick" student 1, student 5 will also be changed to a tick (despite being out of view). And if I tick student 2, student 6 will be ticked. This works vice versa also. I know the onClick code is not executing for the "randomly changed rows" because despite being ticked these rows are not tagged as "ticked". It is very strange to me, here is my code:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.student_listview);
    listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
    listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    listView.setAdapter(new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, studentIDarr)); 
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

            ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);

            if(img.getTag().toString().equals("checked")) {
                checkListArr.set(position, "Absent");
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.remove);
                img.setTag("unchecked");
            } else {
                checkListArr.set(position, "Present");
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.checked);
                img.setTag("checked");
            }  
          }
        });
```

And the Adapter with ViewHolder...

```
static class ViewHolder {
      TextView fname;
      TextView sname;
      TextView ID;
      TextView email;
      ImageView status;
    }

public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
      private final Context context;
      private final ArrayList<String> values;

      public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_class_item, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

          View vi = convertView;
          ViewHolder holder;
          if (convertView == null) {
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_student_item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.fname = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvFname);
                holder.sname = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvSname);
                holder.ID = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvStudentID);
                holder.email = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
                holder.status= (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.icon);

                if(checkListArr.get(position).toString().equals("Absent")) {
                    holder.status.setTag("unchecked");
                } else if (checkListArr.get(position).toString().equals("Present")) {
                    holder.status.setTag("checked");
                }       

                vi.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
            }    

        if(checkListArr.get(position).toString().equals("Absent")) {
            holder.status.setTag("unchecked");
        } else if (checkListArr.get(position).toString().equals("Present")) {
            holder.status.setTag("checked");
        }           

        holder.ID.setText(values.get(position));
        holder.fname.setText(fNameArray.get(position));
        holder.sname.setText(sNameArray.get(position));
        holder.email.setText(emailArray.get(position));
        return vi;
      }
    }
```

Somebody please point out the obvious flaw in my code! Thankyou for reading!

Comment: setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() comment this code and and add vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()) in adapter view of custom adapter. And move all the listeners to adpater itself which are part of list item.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding how a ListView recycles previous views. You need to store these changes inside an underlying data model.

```
public class Model {

  private String fname;
  private String sname;
  private String email;
  private boolean selected;

  public Model(String fname, String sname, String email) {
    this.fname = fname;
    selected = false;
    //etc
  }

  public String getName() {
    return fname;
  }

  public void setName(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
  }

  public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
  }

  public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
  }
  //etc
}
```

Adapter:

```
private final List<Model> list;
    private final Activity context;

    public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.yourlayout, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView text;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
            viewHolder.checkbox
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                boolean isChecked) {
                            Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox
                                    .getTag();
                            element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                        }
                    });
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for `ViewHolder`.

`convertView` is already inflated view. Inflate when it's value is null. Then find your views and set the proper values according to position in either new or convertView.

Implement `SparseBooleanArray` in the adapter with methods for toggling `<int Position, boolean Absence>`  values. It's optimized HashMap like class for holding and inserting such values. `AdapterView<?>` will give you adapter to interact with it.

ListView also will give you access to a similar array with all selected views for processing and saving.